# Condition in formatting without else

Tags: python, format

Is there a way to skip else in formatting

```
f'\n Last date `{date.loc[i] if date.loc[i] != yesterday else 0}`'
```

I want nothing to be printed in case else.  [image]

Comment: `else ""`?.....

Comment: Or use a proper `if` loop

Comment: No, you have to use else

Comment: @Sayse in that case if else is chosen then I get ``. attached a scrin to my question

Comment: Thats down to your string, not the formatting

Comment: Do you know a way to hide these `` if the value = ""?

Comment: ```"`" + date.loc[i] + "`" if ...```…?